# DCUO Character stuck in Battle Mode?

Tags: dc-universe-online

So my character in DC Universe is a sorcerer and she has great abilities, or at least she did until now. I finally figured out how to queue up for missions and did Area 51. I chose to be a Damager role. However, when I did I realized that she lost a lot of her better punch and kick combos. Now for whatever reason she's constantly either in healer mode or damager mode. I know by pressing up I can go to a menu that allows me to switch between them but I miss having cool combos. How can I get those back??

Answer (score 1):

In-Combat is indicated by the circle with your stance on your player frame (health bar) blinking.  You will be in-combat until an encounter is over, resets, or you rally (and don't get hit/use an ability when you get up).  Area 51, you start in-combat from the spawn point, usually by being scanned by a floating drone.  Try leaving the orange area on your minimap (and staying out of combat ... don't get chased), and waiting approximately 30 seconds.

You can also change stance while in combat if you have an Armory imprinted with a different stance.  You should get a free Armory when you complete the mission to place items in your base at level 8 or 9.  You can purchase more Armories from the Marketplace.  When using an Armory in combat, however, it locks you from using the in-combat armory switch for a set amount of time, indicated by an icon under your player frame.